# Send 2 different types of mails using mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp

I have a set of internal users for my project. Admin can activate/deactivate them. I want to send them a mail saying "your account has been deactivated" when their account is deactivated by admin. Similarly they should receive a mail saying "your account has been activated" when admin activates their account. How can I do this?

I am trying by creating 2 separate lists in mailchimp and two separate campaigns. but when I'm writing mailchimps credentials in my development.js with 2 separate list ids and then trying to get it in my javascript file,it is getting undefined (checked by console.log)..

Is there a way to do it by just single campaign/list?

Here's my development.js code of mailchimp credentials:

```
mailchimp: {
    api_key: "***************-***",
    list_id1: "*********", //internal users
    list_id2: "*********" //internal deactivated users
  },
```

my user.helper.js

```
const config = require('../../config/environment');
const Mailchimp = require('mailchimp-api-3');
const mailchimp = new Mailchimp(config.mailchimp.api_key);

exports.addToDeactivatedList = function (email, name) {
 console.log(mailchimp.list_id1);
 mailchimp.members.create(config.mailchimp.list_id1, {
  email_address: email,
  merge_fields: {
   FNAME: name
  },
  status: 'subscribed'
 }).then(user => { }).catch(e => {
  console.log("deactivate list me add ho gya");
 })
}

exports.addToActivatedList = function (email, name) {
 console.log(mailchimp.list_id2);
 mailchimp.members.create(config.mailchimp.list_id2, {
  email_address: email,
  merge_fields: {
   FNAME: name
  },
  status: 'subscribed'
 }).then(user => { }).catch(e => {
  console.log("activate list me add ho gya");
 })
}
```

and my user.controller.js (selective part only)

```
var helper = require('./user.helper');
.
.
if(req.body.status != user.status){     
        (req.body.status == "active") ? helper.addToActivatedList(user.email, user.name) : helper.addToDeactivatedList(user.email, user.name);          
      }
```

All the help will be appreciated. THANKS

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to put everyone in the same list, and then create segments based on that list. After that, create a campaign based on that segment.

You could for instance create a custom list attribute that records wether or not an account is activated and create a segment based on that attribute. The campaign should then be based on that segment.

Perhaps also record the date an account has been activated or deactivated by the admin in another custom attribute and use that to check if a user already had an activation/deactivation mail.

Answer (score 0):

MailChimp offers a feature for situations like this called [automations](https://kb.mailchimp.com/automation/create-an-automation). Automations allow you to send individual emails to subscribers when an event is triggered. So instead of creating separate campaigns every time a user is activated or deactivated, you can use just two automations and a single list.

Whether a user is active or not can be tracked with list merge fields. To do this, you'll need to [add a new text merge field](https://kb.mailchimp.com/lists/manage-contacts/manage-list-and-signup-form-fields) to your list. Let's name the field label 'Active'. Uncheck the 'Visible' checkbox so the user can't see it, and name your merge field something like 'ACTIVE'. You can use values like yes/no or true/false to identify the users by their active status.

Next, create your automations, one for activated users and one for deactivated users. You can set a trigger to send the email when a list field value is changed. So just make each of your two automations send the emails when the 'Active' list field values change to either 'yes' or 'no'.

Then all you need to do with the API is subscribe users to a single list whenever their accounts are activated or deactivated. Just make sure the new 'ACTIVE' merge field is set to 'yes' or 'no' when you do this, and any addresses already subscribed will be updated with the new value. So your `mailchimp.members.create()` would look something like this, based on the example from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mailchimp-api-3):

```
mailchimp.members.create(<list_id>, {
    email_address: <user_email>,
    merge_fields: {
       FNAME: name,
       ACTIVE: 'yes' //Or 'no' if being used for deactivated users
    },
    status: 'subscribed'
    })
```